# How can we create dynamic drop down list in Drools(Kie server)?

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I need to work on drop down list in Kie server for Drools using "GUIDED DECISION TABLES".
where I can make drop down list which is constant. But, I need to read the data from backend of code as list of string and then the same I can display in drop down list. I tried multiple source but not found any source to make dynamic data in drop down.
we can have a look where I have created as drop down list ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYjMX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked [in the documentation There is a part "External data sources in enumerations"](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.33.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#enumerations-advanced-ref_drl-rules)?

```
'Applicant.region' : (new com.mycompany.DataHelper()).getListOfRegions()
```

Have a look you have what you need.
Of course, you have to package you java code in a maven artefact that you add as a dependency in your kjar drools maven artefact
Regards